# Can't upgrade PostgreSQL correctly

Tags: postgresql

A long time ago I installed postgresql on my Ubuntu, and everything went well, even today.
I noticed I had PostgreSQL 14 installed (I run `apt upgrade` regularly), but when I checked deeper, I noticed I had several clusters:

```
 cesar > pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
13  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/13/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log
14  main    5434 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
```

I thought I could kill 12 and 13 clusters, but it appears my databases are linked to the 12. I read that I had to dump all the databases, then inject the dump into the 14 cluster. The problem is that when I stop 12 and 13 clusters:

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql@12-main
sudo systemctl stop postgresql@13-main
```

I can't use the 14 cluster: if I run `pg_dump --version`, version 12 still appears. I thought I could restart postgresql service, with `sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service`, and Postgresql would recognize the last cluster as the good one, but it actually restarted 12 and 13 clusters...

I really don't know how to get rid of 12 and 13 clusters and get my data in the 14 cluster smoothly.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: On debian-derived systems, `pg_dump` and other commands are wrappers around the individual version of binaries installed. This link shows you how to pick the paths to the tool you want. https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/03/27/postgresql-upgrade-using-pg_dump-pg_restore/

Comment: At command line do `man pg_wrapper`. If you want to run a specific version of `pg_dump` do something like `pg_dump --version --cluster 14/main`. You should also do `man pg_upgradecluster`. **Before you use  pg_upgradecluster** I would take a backup of the 12 cluster via `pg_dump` to be on safe side. If the database is small a dump/restore might be just as easy as upgrade. When you have the data migrated you can use `pg_dropcluster` per `man pg_dropcluster`. Then if you don't want the old version `apt remove/purge` the specific version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:

```
# backup ofeverything in my 12 cluster
pg_dumpall > megabackup
# backup the pg_hba.conf
sudo cp /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf ~/pg_hba.conf.12.bck
# stopping and dropping the useless clusters
sudo systemctl stop postgresql@12-main
sudo systemctl stop postgresql@13-main
pg_dropcluster --stop 12 main
pg_dropcluster --stop 13 main
# changing the port of cluster 14 in the conf from 5434 to 5432
sudo vi /etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf
# restarting PG to take the changes into account
sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service
# deleting older versions
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-12 postgresql-13
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/postgresql/12
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/postgresql/13
```

At this point I have the correct version of pg_dump: `pg_dump --version` shows me version 14.

Finally I restore my data:

```
psql -d postgres -f megabackup
```

Comment: You still have multiple versions of `pg_dump` installed. Read `man pg_wrapper` for how the version of a binary is selected e.g *...calls the appropriate version of the desired program to connect to that cluster and database ... 7.  If only one cluster exists on the local system, that one will be selected.  8.  If several clusters exist on the local system, the one listening on the default port 5432 will be selected.*. FYI, `psql` will always be the latest version availble.

Comment: OK I ran `sudo find / -name pg_dump` and I indeed found older versions. I edit my answer to complete it